# Exercise of Measurable Functions

Tags: measure-theory

Let ($\mathbb{N}$, $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$) and $f(n)$= $\tfrac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} $ with $n\in \mathbb{N}$, I need to prove that this function is measurable or not
Could give me some suggestions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that since your sigma algebra consists of all subsets of $\mathbb{N}$, every set is measurable, and hence every function is a measurable function.

Comment: Yeah, without any further details...there is nothing to prove here.